# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never' in obj[key]

Tags: typescript

Help me, please. I don't understand what's wrong.
I have a function that edits a form. I tried to set the param value of function "editCloneStateForm" type `typeof this.form`
but it doesn't work too. My code:

```
editCloneStateForm (value: string, key: IServiceDoneItemKeys) {
    if (this.index >= 0) {
      this.cloneStateForm[this.index].cdate = value
    } else {
      this.form[key] = value // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
    }
  }

form: IServiceDoneItem = {
    id: 0,
    cdate: '',
    counterparty_id: '',
    counterparty_name: '',
    contract_id: '',
    contract_number: '',
    service_id: '',
    statement_id: null,
    service_count: 0,
    cost: 0,
    income: 0,
    agents_commission: 0,
    state_duty: 0,
    ukap: ''
  }
```

```
export interface IServiceDoneItem {
  id?: number,
  cdate: string,
  counterparty_id: number | string,
  counterparty_name: string,
  contract_id: number | string,
  contract_number: string,
  service_id: number | string,
  statement_id: number | null,
  service_count: number,
  cost: number,
  income: number,
  agents_commission: number,
  state_duty: number,
  ukap: string
}

export type IServiceDoneItemKeys = keyof IServiceDoneItem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Updated answer

The original answer would allow you to add any key to your object which might be something you want to avoid, you might only want those specific key/value pairs.

This would keep your interface strict to the specified keys:

```
editCloneStateForm(value: string, key: IServiceDoneItemKeys) {
  if (this.index >= 0) {
    this.cloneStateForm[this.index].cdate = value;
  } else {
    (this.form as Record<IServiceDoneItemKeys, IServiceDoneItem[keyof IServiceDoneItem]>)[key] = value;
  }
}
```

But you should probably check the type of the key as your `value` argument is typed as `string` so we would only want to assign keys which allow value types of `string`

### Original answer

Typescript does not know which type the key you're accessing on your interface `ISserviceDoneItem` is in advance.

You could create a generic to extend:

```
export interface Dictionary<T> {
  [key: string]: T;
}

export interface IServiceDoneItem extends Dictionary<string | number | undefined | null> {
  id?: number;
  cdate: string;
  counterparty_id: number | string;
  counterparty_name: string;
  contract_id: number | string;
  contract_number: string;
  service_id: number | string;
  statement_id: number | null;
  service_count: number;
  cost: number;
  income: number;
  agents_commission: number;
  state_duty: number;
  ukap: string;
}
```

This will allow the types of any of your keys on your interface.